# Scala - Gatling check jsonPath if one element is gte another element

Tags: scala-gatling

I have the following JSON response of an API which I want to test with Gatling (Scala) checks.

```
running_event": {
        "event_name": "Running Event",
        "event_start_time": 1664127840,
        "event_end_time": 1665769440
}
```

I need to check if the `event_end_time` is greater than or equal to `event_start_time`.
How can I do it using Gatling Scala?
Thanks.